# How to display Datetime considering offset using MomentJS with Timezones

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using moment.js with timezones to create a datetime belonging to a specific timezone:

```
var datetime = moment.tz("2016-08-16 21:51:28","Europe/London");
```

Because this constructor is aware of DST (daylight saving time), moment.js will add +1 hour offset automatically. `datetime.format()` will show: `2016-08-16T21:51:28+01:00`.

But it seems when printing the date, the offset ins't considered. E.g. `datetime.format('DD.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss')` will show: `16.08.2016 - 21:51:28` but I wan't it to show: `16.08.2016 - 22:51:28` (the time considering the DST-Offset of 1 hour). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pe1gtbgj/ Also. the documentation may help http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/date-time-math/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the output you're getting.

When you see `+01:00` at the end of an ISO8601 timestamp, it doesn't mean that you need to add an hour.  It means that timestamp given is in a local time zone that is one hour ahead of UTC at that point in time.  Moment isn't adding an hour.  It's simply reflecting the local time in London.

For the timestamps you provided, showing `22:51:28` would be an error.  The local time in London is `21:51:28`, and the equivalent UTC time is `20:51:28`.  You wouldn't find `22:51:28` until you went one time zone to the East, at UTC+2.

Now, if what you *meant* to do is convert *from UTC* to London time, then you need to create the input as UTC and then convert.

```
moment.utc("2016-08-16 21:51:28").tz("Europe/London")
```

Then you'd get `22:51:28` when formatting, which is the result you asked for, but this is a *different* point in time.